# JOGL glReadPixel with long paramater

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm doing some stuff with OpenGL in Java using JOGL and I came across something that surprised me.

There is two glReadPixel functions that points to the same C implementation.

The first one is :

```
glReadPixels(int x, int y, int width, int height, int format, int type, Buffer pixels)
```

I understand how it works compared to the C binding but the second one :

```
glReadPixels(int x, int y, int width, int height, int format, int type, long pixels_buffer_offset)
```

How can it convert a void* to a long ? Are we really getting the pixels within a long ?

I really do not understand the second binding. I have done some googling and I just found out everyone is using the first one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second binding would be used if you want to read the result into a PBO (Pixel Buffer Object). In that case, the last argument is an offset into the buffer. If a buffer is bound to `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER`, the last argument of `glReadPixels()` specifies an offset relative to the start of this buffer.

This is very similar to `glVertexAttribPointer()`, where the last argument is overloaded in the C/C++ bindings, but Java needs two bindings because it is more type safe. In that case, if a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding exists, the last argument is an offset relative to the start of the VBO, otherwise it's a pointer to the data.